# keep cmd after execution of a .exe file open

Tags: cmd, exe

I am trying to run the .exe of a programm I donwloaded. But to see why it isn`t working I want to keep the cmd open to see the output it generates. Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `/K` switch: `cmd /K "my.exe"`.

Comment: okay. guess I was just too stupid to type it in properly ^^` thanks a lot.